# Is there a solution that feels less clumsy than Convert.ChangeType to get the value from a HashTable

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0

I'm in the midst of refactoring some .NET 1.1 code to be a bit more maintainable .NET 4.0 code, and get a feel for what a total overhaul of the code would have.

A big part of the current code depends on [HashTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) instances that are basically a kind of property bags containing values of simple value types like int/double/single and string.

Around that are huge chunks of mostly copy/paste code doing conversions, and quite a few of those places are "almost" copies containing bugs.

Hence my plan for a `LoadValue` function like below.

The logic in the application presumes strings are never null, and always trimmed.
In my method below, based on [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx), the solution for this feels 'clumsy', so:

- is there a less clumsy way of doing this?
- am I overlooking any obvious things in this method?

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Centralize all the null/value behaviour for converting properties in bags to business object properties.
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">type to get; can be simple value type (int, double, etc) or string</typeparam>
  /// <param name="properties">HashTable to get property from</param>
  /// <param name="propertyName">name of property to get</param>
  /// <returns>default(T) if property does not have value, otherwise Trimmed value for string, or value for other types.</returns>
  protected T LoadValue<T>(Hashtable properties, string propertyName)
  {
      T result;
      bool haveValue = properties[propertyName] != null;
      Type genericType = typeof(T);
      Type stringType = typeof(string);
      if (genericType.IsSubclassOf(stringType))
      {
          string stringResult;
          if (haveValue)
              stringResult = ((string)properties[propertyName]).Trim();
          else
              stringResult = string.Empty;
          result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(stringResult, genericType); //(T)(stringResult);
      }
      else
      {
          if (haveValue)
              result = ((T)properties[propertyName]);
          else
              result = default(T);
      }
      return result;
  }
  ```

Comment: You say the HashTables contain ints, doubles, and singles, but you sort of imply these get encoded as strings. Are you saying you have numbers stored as strings in the HashTable that you want to extract as numbers?

Comment: @TimRogers int/double/single are not stored as strings. How can I rectify that implication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `System.String` is `sealed`, the expression

```
genericType.IsSubclassOf(stringType)
```

is the same as

```
genericType==stringType
```

Therefore you do not need a call of `Convert.ChangeType`: you can cast to `T` by casting to `object`, like this:

```
object stringResult; // Note the change of type to "object"
if (haveValue)
    stringResult = ((string)properties[propertyName]).Trim();
else
    stringResult = string.Empty;
result = (T)stringResult; // It is allowed to cast object to generic T
```

Comment: Queued a blog post about this. Thanks again!